# Command: Emacs selection → \command{regexp'ed-selection}

Tags: emacs, auctex

Suppose I have the following text:

> …as shown in figure (24).

Now, suppose I select "(24)." Then, I want a command to convert it to:

> …as shown in figure \command{eq:24}.

Viz., how would I define a new Emacs command that I could place in `~/.emacs` that would run `C-C RET command RET` on a regexp'ed version of the selected text? thanks

thanks

Comment: `C-C RET command RET`

Comment: Do you want to bind another key to the same function `C-c RET command RET` runs?  Why this?

Comment: @giordano: Because there's some regexp`ing in addition, too. "(24)" needs to be regexp`ed to "eq:24" *and* then `C-c RET command RET` can run on that.

Comment: I think the easiest option here is to carefully record a keyboard macro and then save it. Then, look over what you did (command wise) and make a proper LISP macro.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function <kbd>C-c RET</kbd>`command`<kbd>RET</kbd> runs is `(TeX-insert-macro "command")`, so this code does what you want

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "INSERT-YOUR-KEYBINDING-HERE")
       (lambda (beg end)
     (interactive "^r")
     (if (> (point) (mark))
         (exchange-point-and-mark))
     (re-search-forward "(\\([^)]*\\))" (mark) t)
     (replace-match  "eq:\\1")
     (goto-char beg)
     (TeX-insert-macro "command")
     (pop-mark)))))
```

You can adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: How do I do the regexp'ing? Viz., what do I fill in for "command"? thanks

Comment: Also, your code is missing a final ")".

Comment: I've updated the answer, now it should be complete.  In the previous code there was no missing `)`.

Comment: @Geremia have you seen the updated answer?  Is it OK now?